# using python decorators with property inside of a class

Tags: python, class, properties, decorator

I am trying to use properties and decorators in a class, but the problem I keep running into is getting the correct arguments, and the number of arguments.

```
class Xml(object):
    def __init__(self, data_dictionary=None):
        self.data_dictionary = data_dictionary

    def xml_wrapper(xml_msg):
        def wrap():
            return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'+xml_msg['name']
        return wrap


    @property
    @xml_wrapper
    def data_dictionary(self):
        return self._data_dictionary

    @data_dictionary.setter
    def data_dictionary(self, data):
        self._data_dictionary = data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml = Xml()
    xml.data_dictionary = {'name': 'name 1'}
    print xml.data_dictionary
```

The error I am getting is

```
 print xml.data_dictionary
TypeError: wrap() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I am not sure why, I tried adding self to the xml_wrapper function but I still get an error.

Comment: `data_dictionary` is being wrapped by `xml_wrapper` decorator which returns a function(`wrap`) that does not take any argument; but when you are calling `xml.data_dictionary` the implicit argument `xml` (the `self`) is being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the `xml_wrapper` is a decorator which takes a function, then wraps it with another function (`wrap`) and returns it. The function `wrap` does not take any argument(as in your code). But  when you call `xml.data_dictionary`, python is implicitly passing the instance `xml` (known as `self`) which is causing the problem. May be this is what you want:

```
>>> class Xml(object):
        def __init__(self, data_dictionary=None):
            self.data_dictionary = data_dictionary

        def xml_wrapper(f):
            def wrap(*k,**kw):
                xml_msg = f(*k,**kw)
                return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'+xml_msg['name']
            return wrap


        @property
        @xml_wrapper
        def data_dictionary(self):
            return self._data_dictionary

        @data_dictionary.setter
        def data_dictionary(self, data):
            self._data_dictionary = data


>>> xml = Xml()
>>> xml.data_dictionary = {"name":"name 1"}
>>> print xml.data_dictionary
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
name 1
```

This time xml_wrapper is taking a function (`data_dictionary`) then calls this function to get the `xml_msg` (inside `wrap`). `wrap` now takes arbitrarily many arguments and just passes those to original function (`data_dictionary`), takes the value, formats it, and returns.

Comment: Since, xml_wrapper isn't part of the class(meaning it doesn't have self as the first argument) should I put it inside of the class or have it as a stand alone function?  What is the pythonic way to do it?

Comment: I think it is a matter of preference. As the decorator has nothing to do with `self`, indeed it can be put in another module. But, as the class is processing Xml, it also makes sense to put that decorator inside the class. I prefer the later.